# Using enum with BehaviorRelay brings a different type of value downstream and makes it impossible to handle

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am trying to implement UI state using a `ViewModel`, `BehaviorRelay`, and `State` (which is an enum).

**In the ViewModel:**

```
class MyViewModel {
    ...
    let state = BehaviorRelay<State?>(value: nil)
    ...
}
```

**Observing changes in VC:**

```
viewModel.state.asDriver().drive { state in
    // Problem is here. "state" seems to be of type Observable<State?> instead of actual State enum
}
```

**Here's how I see the type that comes from the Driver:**

[image]

**And here's a bunch of errors when I try to handle it using switch:**

[image]

I am using the exact same code to observe other types of data and it works. It seems only when I try to use BehaviorRelay with enums, this happens. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
```

---

```
viewModel.state.subscribe { [weak self] (state) in 
    
}.disposed(by:disposeBag)
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I am just learning RxSwift (only done RxJava up until now) and I had no idea this pattern that forces you to properly clean up disposables even exists. Thank you!